# How to manage chrome local storage

Tags: python, selenium, local-storage, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using `Selenium` + `Python` + `ChromeDriver` to test web application. Web application contains tables with data that could be sorted using various embedded filters. The problem is that after first test executed application saves current state (like which table page is opened, which data sorting method applied) in browser local storage, so that when next test starts data appears already filtered... But I need default data filters for each test and so I need to set default `key`:`value` pairs or clear storage before each test case. I found this solution

```
driver.get('javascript:localStorage.clear();')
```

but get

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:unsupported protocol
```

How can I manage (change or clear) `Chrome` local storage using `Selenium`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *execute the script* instead:

```
driver.execute_script('window.localStorage.clear();')
```